# How do I recreate a user/login on a SQL Azure Active Geo-Replication Secondary

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services, azure-sql-database, geo-replication

I have a Premium P2 SQL Azure Database for my Production App, and for security reasons I've created DB Specific Schemas/Views/Roles and a specific DB User account for reading the Data from SSRS Queries.

Lets just call the server `PRIMARY` and my database `MyApp`

The setup script for this is below.

```
-- On Primary Master
CREATE LOGIN ssrsuser WITH password='******'

-- On Primary MyApp
CREATE USER ssrsuser FOR LOGIN ssrsuser 
CREATE ROLE [ssrsreader] AUTHORIZATION [db_owner]
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: [App] TO [ssrsreader]
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: [Reports] TO [ssrsreader]
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'ssrsreader', 'ssrsuser'
```

So our users were putting a LOT of load on the Prod DB and we decided it was time to move the reporting functions off to a secondary sync'd slave database.

Since we're using the SQL Azure Premium Tier, we can enable Active Geo-Replication with a read-only secondary copy. [In fact MS even say that it's suitable for read-only workloads such as reporting.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741339.aspx)

So I've setup the `SECONDARY` server, enabled the seeding, it's now complete and I can access the readonly copy using the `SECONDARY` admin user and password.

But the `SECONDARY` server doesn't have a login for `ssrsuser` and I while I can create one in `SECONDARY.master`, I can't `DROP RECREATE` the user since the `SECONDARY.MyApp` database is in readonly mode.

Is there any otherway to get around this. I really don't want to have to put the `SECONDARY` server admin user & password into SSRS connection strings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no need to regenerate SID for ssruser in the user database. It is already there as a result of replication. All you need to do is associate that SID with a LOGIN in the master in the secondary server. This article provides the details.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-geo-replication-security-config/

I hope this helps.